# Possible bug/misunderstanding of splice and slice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the next loop:

```
    rolling_average_delta_follower=[];
    followers=[32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56] // .length = 12
    delta_followers=[50,52,54,56,58,60,62,64,66,68,70,72,74]  // leng= 12

     for (i = 0; i < followers.length ; i++) {

                copie = delta_followers.slice(0); //creates duplicate of array delta_followers so I keep source original and not cut from it
                copie.splice(7,i) // supposed to create an array that contains numbers from 50 to 64 -> next time the for executes it should go 52 to 66 and so on
                console.log(copie)
                for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {  // the 7 numbers added previously in the one array are getting summed up
                    totalx += copie[i]
                }
                rolling_average_delta_follower.push(totalx) // the sum of each array previously created is getting added to the main array where I need the data.


        }
```

All good until I try to actually execute it, I end up with with a forever loop that I seem not to be able to escape.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {  // the 7 numbers added previously in the one array are getting summed up
    totalx += copie[i]
}
```

By this code you override `i` used in the loop above.
Just use another variable name here. (`j` ?)

Comment: thank you , that was indeed the problem of the loop , any idea on how could I make the splice work  like I described above? Right now after I tested it ,  it only removes one element by one from the end of the array. It doesn't progressively select 7 values

Answer (score 1):

To make a copy of an array use the spread operator.

```
const copy = [...original];
```

To sum the values of an array use reduce.

```
const sum = array.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item, 0);
```

Comment: how could I do it so splice will work like I described above? I just tested the splice and it only removes an element one by one from the end of the array

Comment: Explain what you algorithm is trying to do.

Comment: copie.splice(7,i) // supposed to create an array that contains numbers from 50 to 64(7 numbers) -> next time the for executes it should go 52 to 66(the next 7 numbers) and so on